# Seg fault in c++ template class

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm new to c++ and I was trying to implement my own hash table. The issue occur in the add method of the class. It works perfectly on my mac but when I try and run it on a computer running ubuntu it seg faults. This also works without any errors when I use integers instead of the std::string class.

Here is the code in main:

```
Hash<string> * load(string filename);
int main(void) {
    Hash<string> *dict = load("words.txt");
    
}
Hash<string> * load(string filename) {
    ifstream in = ifstream(filename);
    if (!in) {
        throw FileNotFoundError();
    }
    Hash<string> * hash = new Hash<string>(hashfunction);
    string buff;
    while(in >> buff) {
        hash -> add(buff);
    }
    in.close();
    return hash;
}
```

The issue occurs in the add method of the Hash class

```
template <typename T>
class Hash {
private:
    int size;
    Node<T> **nodes;
    int (*hash)(T obj);
    int arrsize;
    static int constexpr const standard = 1000000;
public:
    Hash(int (*hash)(T obj), int arrsize = standard)
        :hash(hash),arrsize(arrsize),size(0){
            nodes = new Node<T> *[arrsize];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
                nodes[i] = nullptr;
            }

    }
    bool add(T &&obj) {
        add(obj);
    }
    bool add(T &obj) {
        size_t code = hash(obj) % arrsize;
        Node<T> *n = new Node<T>(obj, nodes[code]);
        nodes[code] = n;
        size ++;
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the node class for reference

```
template  <typename T>
class Node {
private:
    T obj; 
    Node *next;
    friend bool operator==(Node &left, T& obj) {
        return left.obj == obj;
    }
public:
    Node(T obj)
        :Node(obj, nullptr){

    }
    Node(T obj, Node *next) 
        :obj(obj),next(next) {

    }
    void deleter() {
        if (next) {
            next -> deleter();
        }
        delete this;
    }
    Node * getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    void setNext(Node * next) {
       this -> next = next;
    }

};
```

Hash Function

```
//Uses Hash function djb2 by Dan Bernstein http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
int hashfunction(string words){
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;
    const char *word = words.c_str();
    while ((c = *word++))
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + tolower(c); /* hash * 33 + c */
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your hash function?

Comment: Sorry about that I edited my question to show the hash function @Manuel

Comment: first add doesn't return a value

Comment: Note: If the compiler doesn't know the `((hash << 5) + hash)` => `hash * 33` trick and make use of it, it's a pretty crummy compiler. Prefer clear code. The function could be `unsigned long hash = 5381; for (char ch: words) { hash = 33* hash + tolower(cc); } return hash;` and there shouldn't be any performance difference.

Comment: What kind of input do you have? I'm hashing the string `<time.h>` and having a hash of `7570595933782724` and `code` `18446744073708595908`, which is way beyond the nodes array size.

Comment: @Manuel thank you for helping me figure that out. The mistake I made was really dumb. Instead of  ```size_t code = hash(obj) % arrsize``` I meant to do ```size_t code = hash(obj); code %= arrsize;```I think this is a sign I should probably take a break and get some sleep.